# Android WebView content layout different in Samsung's easy mode

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-webview, viewport, samsung-mobile

I have a problem with Samsung's "Easy Mode".

Our C# application is developed using Android.Webkit.WebViewClient where we call some Web pages (HTML / CSS / JS) as a user interface. All views respond to all types of different devices. Also, all views work as expected running in "normal mode".

As soon as you activate the "Easy Mode" of Samsung devices, the webview appears to change the fontfactor and other important layout rules. Due to complicated controls but limited screen space, we are now forced to ensure that our views are not affected by easy mode or alternatively are resized to their optimal state.

I've already tried some viewport settings on the pages and some properties on the webview instance but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any idea how to force deactivation or how to detect and react on easy mode using web technologies or the webview instance?

I am definitely grateful for any help or advice!

Thanks!

Comment: This is a problem faced in Android apps coded in Java & Kotlin as well. There's seems to be no developer documentation for the Easy Mode. Could you please share pictures of the effects of turning it on? The web developer should be able to update the CSS to manage any distortions though.

Comment: I'm not able to provide screens at the moment. But it seems lik the font size is automatically adjusted in the web forms in easy mode.So the font size seems to be the indicator for any missplaced layout parts. It leads to overflow of some elements.